# Cannot connect to MySQL docker container from container with Django app

Tags: mysql, django, docker

When I try to connect from a docker container running my Django app to a container running MySQL, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.2' (111)")
```

Here's how I'm running the MySQL container:

```
$ docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=172.17.0.2 -d mysql/mysql-server:5.7
```

If I don't specify `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST`, I get this error when I try to connect from the container with the Django app:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1130, "Host '172.17.0.3' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")
```

Here are my Django settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'testdb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '172.17.0.2',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

I've verified the MySQL container is using IP 172.17.0.2:

```
$ docker inspect mysql |grep -i ipaddress
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
```

Comment: Is the name of your database docker container mysql ?

Comment: Yes the name is mysql.

Comment: MySql usually takes a few seconds to start up, are you trying to connect to it immediately or after a little bit? Also, fwiw, it doesn't look like you need to specify `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST` when you start the container.

Comment: try putting your container name, 'mysql', as the HOST value in the django db settings. That's how I have it in mine.

Comment: I've waited a minute after starting the MySQL container, and I get the same results.  I get different results whether I specify ```MYSQL_ROOT_HOST```, and I'll update my post.

Comment: Your django says "Host '172.17.0.3' is not allowed", but your MySQL IP is '172.17.0.2', is that correct?

Comment: denvaar, I changed HOST to mysql, but no difference.  Haoming Zhang, yes, the Django app container IP is .3 and the MySQL container IP is .2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to grant the root user at the Django container permissions to access the DB:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'172.17.0.3' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'172.17.0.3' = PASSWORD('root');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Where `172.17.0.3` is the IP of the container with the app.  `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST` is not needed.

Comment: dirty solution though, the IP of the web container is not always the same.

Answer (score 7):

`docker run --rm -d -p 9999:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST='%' mysql/mysql-server:5.7`

The important part is `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST='%'`

Comment: What the heck is %

Comment: MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%' to allow root connecting from any address

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is fully documented here: (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker#mysql_root_host) and works as expected.
I'll quote it:

> By default, MySQL creates the 'root'@'localhost' command. This account
>   can only be connected to from inside the container, requiring the use
>   of the docker exec command as noted under Connect to MySQL from the
>   MySQL Command Line Client. To allow connections from other hosts, set
>   this environment variable. As an example, the value "172.17.0.1",
>   which is the default Docker gateway IP, will allow connections from
>   the Docker host machine.

You can see actual `.sh` script which set allowed host from this env variable: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/5.7/docker-entrypoint.sh#L63-L68

Comment: So it's not possible to do what I'm doing?  The only way to connect to a MySQL container (at least by using the official image) is from the container itself?

Comment: Yes. But why is this an issue for you?

Comment: Isn't it a valid use case to have the database running in a container and the app running in another container?

Comment: Yes, absolutely valid. And I usually put dbhost in some kind of environment variable which is different in production settings and development settings (I have separate files for this). `DATABASES` dict only references those env. variables so you don't have to change anything in your code. May be only write simple .sh script which will run your containers with same ip every time

Comment: Official documentation should mention the example usage and connectivity setup between containers. They just say about `link` command and nothing about the permissions: https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/
Followed the documentation and still getting the: `ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '172.26.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`

Answer (score 1):

As @valignatev suggested, using this env variable solves an issue.

I did create container this way:

```
 docker run --rm -dit -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=172.17.0.1 --name mysql_container -p 3306:3306 mysql-mysql-server
```

172.17.0.1 is my default docker gateway

Once container gets started I can connect from my host like this:

```
 mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root -p
```

Comment: It seems that you are trying to connect from host to the MySQL container. My problem was that I couldn't connect from the Django container to the MySQL container.

Comment: This doesn't exactly address the OP's question but 100% solves mine. I could not connect from host to MySQL container. FYI, this should work too: `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=172.*.*.*`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will be helpful but I had a similar issue and got it to work by adding `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%`
This is what my docker-compose looks like for the db:

```yaml
mysql:
  platform: linux/x86_64
  image: mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=foobar123
    - MYSQL_USER=test_user
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=foobar123
  volumes:
    - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  ports:
    - 3306:3306
  container_name: "mysql"
```

Source documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/docker-mysql-more-topics.html#docker_var_mysql-root-host