# laravel+docker: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '172.22.0.4' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

Tags: docker, mariadb

I want to be able, locally, to connect from my app container to my db container using root, without any password, from any ip.

in my `docker-compose.yml` I defined a db serice as

```
    db:
        image: mariadb
        container_name: docker-mariadb
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: docker-db
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: yes
        volumes:
            - ./db/:/var/lib/mysql/
        networks:
             - docker-network
```

laravel `.env` file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=docker-db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I am getting, at first Laravel query, the error

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host '172.22.0.4' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server

So base networking is working, but mysql is refusing connection to my root user

### Edit 1  - Users on db container

I accessed mariadb container, and obtained user list

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
+-------------+--------------+
| User        | Host         |
+-------------+--------------+
| root        | 127.0.0.1    |
| root        | ::1          |
| root        | a1a831ff7300 |
| mariadb.sys | localhost    |
| root        | localhost    |
+-------------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.002 sec)
```

### Question

**What can i do to fix it?**

> Notes: I don't want to manually change host or add another root@% user manually.
> Also I need a way to do these things using docker-compose to be able to distribute docker-compose and all related files to coworkers to spin up a full working environment without having to do things manually

Comment: You should login locally to the DB server and ALTER the user to have the host as `%` (all hosts)

Comment: I must be able to rebuild full environment. I cannot alter environment manually after building it. But this error is not saying me that an user cannot login from the host . It says the IP of other container cannot connect to mysql container. So it is not an user configuration problem I think. But I will try

Comment: Similar issue described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40825617/cannot-connect-to-mysql-docker-container-from-container-with-django-app - maybe you should try to remove quotes from MYSQL_ROOT_HOST? Sorry, overlooked from above snippet

Comment: MYSQL_ROOT_HOST is actually doing nothing. And it's undocumented. Also, removing quote will cause a syntax error because of YAML file format of docker-compose file

Comment: There is a snippet in the latest comment from docker-compose, all env variables starts with - (dashes). So it is the list. It must be a syntax issue as for others it worked

Comment: And the vars are documented here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-docker-environment-variables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checked on my virtual machine. No need for db init script

After adding to `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
```

you should do a `docker-compose down` and delete the volume `./db/`:

```
rm -rf ./db/
```

and do a `docker-compose up -d` again - my results:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| User        | Host      |
+-------------+-----------+
| mybb        | %         |
| root        | %         |
| mariadb.sys | localhost |
| root        | localhost |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Comment: I cleaned up, retried, and your're right. No need for init script. it simply works. My fault.